# Redirect http to https but different port in IIS 8.5 for my .net core application

Tags: ssl, iis, regex, iis-8.5

I have my .net core application. The http site is http://www.myfakesite.com:5000 But my https site is https://www.myfakesite.com:5001.

What I want is when I open the http site it will be re-directed to https site.

You see the port is also changed from 5000 to 5001.

I followed the [steps](https://tecadmin.net/iis-redirect-http-to-https/), but I don't know how to modify the rule.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the URL that you posted, if shows you need to put this in your redirect URL section:

```
https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}
```

So it should just be a matter of adding the port as so:

```
https://{HTTP_HOST}:5001/{R:1}
```

This should add port 5001 onto the end of the hostname and direct accordingly.

Comment: I don't think it works as the port number is included in the HTTP_HOST variable. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19257193/in-iis-url-rewrite-2-0-why-does-http-host-include-the-port-number

Comment: Good point. I wanted to do it as a comment but I don't have enough points as yet. I guess this didn't help lol.

Comment: So please delete your answer. Otherwise your answer might be down voted by other people. Thanks